# Why is the hash getting modified? Java crypto

Tags: java, encryption, hash, cryptography

I am writing code to encrypt and decrypt files using a seed, as well as needing to verify the hash of the file to ensure it was not modified. The hash calculates perfectly fine, and is appended to the plaintext file. The encryption also works as when I decrypt the ciphertext with the same seed input, I get the original plaintext back as well as some hash. However this hash is not *exactly* the same as the original file's (I do not even open the ciphertext File, and the difference is 1 byte). Could someone help me out? Thanks,

Here is the encryption invoked with command line arguments [plaintext file]
[seed]

```
public static KeyGenerator key_gen = null;
public static SecretKey sec_key = null;
public static byte[] raw = null;
private static SecretKeySpec sec_key_spec = null;
private static Cipher sec_cipher = null;

//for DSA
private static KeyPairGenerator keypairgen = null;
private static KeyPair keypair = null;
private static DSAPrivateKey private_key = null;
private static DSAPublicKey public_key = null;
private static Signature dsa_sig = null;
private static SecureRandom secRan = null;

public static void main(String args[]){
    FileInputStream in_file = null;
    FileInputStream in_file2 = null;
    FileOutputStream out_file = null;
    byte[] sha_hash = null;
    //byte[] hmac_hash = null;
    byte[] aes_ciphertext = null;
    int read_bytes = 0;

    try{
        //open files
        in_file = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        out_file = new FileOutputStream("CipherText.txt");
        byte[] seed = args[1].getBytes();

        //read file into a byte array
        byte[] msg = new byte[in_file.available()];
        read_bytes = in_file.read(msg);

        //SHA-1 Hash
        sha_hash = sha1_hash(msg);
        byte[] concatenatedMSG = new byte[msg.length + sha_hash.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < concatenatedMSG.length; i++)
        {
            if(i < msg.length)
                concatenatedMSG[i] = msg[i];
            else
                concatenatedMSG[i] = sha_hash[i - msg.length];

        }

        //print out hash in hex
        System.out.println("SHA-1 Hash: " + toHexString(sha_hash));

        //encrypt file with AES
        //key setup - generate 128 bit key

        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        rand.setSeed(seed);

        key_gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        key_gen.init(128, rand);
        sec_key = key_gen.generateKey();

        //get key material in raw form
        raw = sec_key.getEncoded();
        sec_key_spec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

        //create the cipher object that uses AES as the algorithm
        sec_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 

        //do AES encryption
        aes_ciphertext = aes_encrypt(concatenatedMSG);
        out_file.write(aes_ciphertext);
        out_file.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

        try{
            if (in_file != null){
                in_file.close();
            }
            if(out_file != null){
                out_file.close();
            }
            if(in_file2 != null){
                in_file2.close();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The output is:
`SHA-1 Hash: 67:0E:EF:99:0B:62:F4:BA:40:78:8C:34:8F:61:9E:40:E4:CF:65:06`

The decryption File: invoked with CipherText.txt [same seed in encrypt]

```
private static KeyGenerator key_gen = null;
private static SecretKey sec_key = null;
private static byte[] raw = null;
private static SecretKeySpec sec_key_spec = null;
private static Cipher sec_cipher = null;

//for DSA
private static KeyPairGenerator keypairgen = null;
private static KeyPair keypair = null;
private static DSAPrivateKey private_key = null;
private static DSAPublicKey public_key = null;
private static Signature dsa_sig = null;
private static SecureRandom secRan = null;
public static void main(String args[])
 {
    FileInputStream in_file = null;
    FileInputStream in_file2 = null;
    FileOutputStream out_file = null;
    String decrypted_str = new String();
    int read_bytes = 0;

    try{
        //open files
        in_file = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        byte[] seed = args[1].getBytes();

        //encrypt file with AES
        //key setup - generate 128 bit key
        SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
        rand.setSeed(seed);

        key_gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        key_gen.init(128, rand);
        sec_key = key_gen.generateKey();

        //get key material in raw form
        raw = sec_key.getEncoded();
        sec_key_spec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

        //create the cipher object that uses AES as the algorithm
        sec_cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 

        //decrypt file
        byte[] ciphtext = new byte[in_file.available()];
        in_file.read(ciphtext); 

        decrypted_str = aes_decrypt(ciphtext);

        byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypted_str.getBytes();
        byte[] decryptedMSG = new byte[decryptedBytes.length - 20];
        byte[] decryptedHash = new byte[20];

        System.out.print(decrypted_str);
        System.out.print("\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < decryptedMSG.length; i++)
            decryptedMSG[i] = decryptedBytes[i];

        for(int i = 0; i < decryptedHash.length; i++)
            decryptedHash[i] = decryptedBytes[i+ decryptedMSG.length];

        String decryptedCalcSHA = toHexString(sha1_hash(decryptedMSG));
        String fileSHA = toHexString(decryptedHash);

        System.out.println("DEC:" +decryptedCalcSHA);
        System.out.println("FIL:" +fileSHA);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

        try{
            if (in_file != null){
                in_file.close();
            }
            if(out_file != null){
                out_file.close();
            }
            if(in_file2 != null){
                in_file2.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e2)
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The decrypt outputs:

```
This is a test message to see if the file decrypts properly. Nothing special 
in this file.
Juts a pure test to see if my code works. Two chemists walk into a bar...
gï™bôº@xŒ4?až@äÏe
DEC:67:0E:EF:99:0B:62:F4:BA:40:78:8C:34:8F:61:9E:40:E4:CF:65:06
FIL:67:0E:EF:99:0B:62:F4:BA:40:78:8C:34:3F:61:9E:40:E4:CF:65:06
```

The difference is the 8F vs 3F, even though the file was not manually modified.

EDIT: The FIL SHA hash, the one with 3F is incorrect, it should be 8F.

Comment: Check which SHA1 hash is correct and then add additional logging to whichever block of code produced the incorrect hash.

Comment: For a start, you are misusing `available()`. There is a specific warning in the Javadoc *against* using it in exactly the way you're using it here.

Comment: @EJP what would you recommend I do then?

Comment: Read the file in chunks and use the `update()` method, calling `doFinal()` at the end. Or use Cipher input and output streams.